# CONSTRAINTEXCEPTION issue in Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I am using Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1  to sync SQLSERVER and SQLSERVERCe databases. Syncing is working fine for simple insert, update and delete operations in any one the databases. Here I am using **upload and download** both for Sync directions. 
but problem occurs when I sync both databases having same primary key values that is ID value is same in syncing database tables. 
 I got this exception error specifically CONSTRAINTEXCEPTION that states "Column 'ID' is constrained to be unique.  Value '5' is already present."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is a valid exception. even without using Sync Framework, you cant insert the same Primary Key value in a table.

see [Selecting an Appropriate Primary Key for a Distributed Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726011%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx) for guidelines in choosing keys for tables in Sync Framework

Comment: thanx JuneT... this article was really very helpful.